# Upload file with carrierwave without name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

It's me again. I try to upload some yaml files with carrierwave. Everything works fine till now.

So, as you know for carrierwave the forms looks like the follow:

```
<%= form_for @resume, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true %>
      <%= f.label :attachment %><br>
      <%= f.file_field :attachment, :required => true %>
      <br><br>
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

What i want to do now is to remove the "name" field. I don't need it. So i thought its quite easy, just remove the "name" part of the form. But then I got an error while upload:

```
Name can't be blank
```

So I tried now nearly everything... I had set the `required => false` same result.
I went to Github and tooked a look at their how-to... there are methods to overwrite the name, but nobody cares about upload a file without a name. May somebody can tell me how i can upload a file without this name field?

Thanks!

Edit:

My resume.rb model:

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader # Tells rails to use this uploader for this model.


end
```

My AttachmentUploader:

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(yml)
  end

  def filename
    "something.jpg" if original_filename # This is the part where i'm trying around right now.
  end

end
```

Comment: Remove the validation from presumably `Resume`

Comment: @j-dexx already done, didn't change anything..

Comment: In the model? Not just changing required to false.

Comment: @j-dexx Yes, in the model. updated my question with the code of my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove column `name` on table `resumes` and others related, 
maybe on views, controller (`strong params`), migration file...

Then re-run drop, migrate database

Comment: Thank you, worked! I tried everything... but I didn't thought that it would be so easy. :P